# JPA SQL Injection

Tags: java, jpa, parameters, sql-injection

I work With JPA and I have some Queries. I have googled but result not found, I have simple question

```
query.setParameter("name","%" + name + "%");
```

Is it precondition for sql injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since you're binding the value to a parameterized query, your code will not cause an SQL injection opportunity.

An SQL injection is usually caused by *not* parameterizing the query but building it and adding parameters using string concatenation.